How want to get user detail from the Azure Directory using C# and Graph API
I want to get user detail using there userPrincipleName or object ID.
I tried like this but they gave me error that I mentioned below.

The expression cannot be evaluated.A common cause of this error is attempting to pass a lambda into a delegate.

This is c# Code
using Azure.Identity;
using Microsoft.Graph;
using Microsoft.Graph.Models;

namespace UserProperties;

public class GraphHandler
{
    public GraphServiceClient GraphClient { get; set; }

    public GraphHandler(string tenantId, string clientId, string clientSecret)
    {
        GraphClient = CreateGraphClient(tenantId, clientId, clientSecret);
    }
    public GraphServiceClient CreateGraphClient(string tenantId, string clientId, string clientSecret)
    {
        var options = new TokenCredentialOptions
        {
            AuthorityHost = AzureAuthorityHosts.AzurePublicCloud            
        };

        var clientSecretCredential = new ClientSecretCredential(tenantId, clientId, clientSecret, options);
        var scopes = new[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };

        return new GraphServiceClient(clientSecretCredential, scopes);
    }

    public async Task<User?> GetUser(string userPrincipalName)
    {
        return await GraphClient.Users[userPrincipalName].GetAsync();
    }

    public void userDetail()
    {
        var user =  GraphClient.Me.GetAsync();
        Console.WriteLine(user);
    }
}


how can I rid out of this, can someone suggest me.
I want to get user Detail from the azure directory.
Thank you

As you are making use of ClientSecretCredential you cannot call /me endpoint. You need to use users/userID endpoint

If you want to call /me endpoint then make use of interactive flow

@Rukmini Can you suggest me how can I do that and can you give me some reference.

Sure I will post it an answer in sometime

Which line shows the error?

@user2250152 now, this question is resolved, all credit goes to Rukmini

The error occurred as you are making use of ClientSecretCredential and calling /me endpoint.

ClientSecretCredential is non interactive flow and /me endpoint works only with user interactive flow.
Hence either switch to user interactive flow or use ClientSecretCredential and call users/UserId endpoint.

Grant application API permissions to use ClientSecretCredential:

And modify the code by changing GraphClient.Users[userId].GetAsync() like below:
using Azure.Identity;
using Microsoft.Graph;
using Microsoft.Graph.Models;
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace UserProperties
{
    public class GraphHandler
    {
        public GraphServiceClient GraphClient { get; set; }

        public GraphHandler()
        {
            var tenantId = "TenantID";
            var clientId = "ClientID";
            var clientSecret = "ClientSecret";
            GraphClient = CreateGraphClient(tenantId, clientId, clientSecret);
        }

        public GraphServiceClient CreateGraphClient(string tenantId, string clientId, string clientSecret)
        {
            var options = new TokenCredentialOptions
            {
                AuthorityHost = AzureAuthorityHosts.AzurePublicCloud
            };

            var clientSecretCredential = new ClientSecretCredential(tenantId, clientId, clientSecret, options);
            var scopes = new[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };

            return new GraphServiceClient(clientSecretCredential, scopes);
        }

        public async Task userDetail()
        {
            try
            {
                // Example usage to get user details directly
                var userId = "UserID"; // Replace with the desired user's ID
                var user = await GraphClient.Users[userId].GetAsync();

                // Print user ID and DisplayName
                Console.WriteLine($"User ID: {user.Id}");
                Console.WriteLine($"Display Name: {user.DisplayName}");
            }
            catch (ServiceException ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Error getting user details: {ex.Message}");
            }
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            GraphHandler handler = new GraphHandler();

            // Example usage to get my details
            await handler.userDetail();
        }
    }
}

The user details displayed successfully like below:

If you want to call /me endpoint, then grant User.Read delegated API permission and refer this MsDoc (except Client credentials provider choose any of the flow) and choose interactive flow to authenticate.
UPDATE:
To get the User Profile Photo, use the below code:
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Azure.Identity;
using Microsoft.Graph;
using Microsoft.Graph.Models;

namespace UserProperties
{
    public class GraphHandler
    {
        public GraphServiceClient GraphClient { get; set; }

        public GraphHandler()
        {
            var tenantId = "TenantID";
            var clientId = "ClientID";
            var clientSecret = "ClientSecret";
            GraphClient = CreateGraphClient(tenantId, clientId, clientSecret);
        }

        public GraphServiceClient CreateGraphClient(string tenantId, string clientId, string clientSecret)
        {
            var options = new TokenCredentialOptions
            {
                AuthorityHost = Azure.Identity.AzureAuthorityHosts.AzurePublicCloud
            };

            var clientSecretCredential = new Azure.Identity.ClientSecretCredential(tenantId, clientId, clientSecret, options);
            var scopes = new[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };

            return new GraphServiceClient(clientSecretCredential, scopes);
        }

        public async Task<User> GetUser(string userId)
        {
            try
            {
                var user = await GraphClient.Users[userId].GetAsync();
                return user;
            }
            catch (ServiceException ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Error getting user details: {ex.Message}");
                return null;
            }
        }

        public async Task PrintProfilePicture(string userId)
        {
            var user = await GetUser(userId);
            if (user != null)
            {
                try
                {
                    using (var photoStream = await GraphClient.Users[userId].Photo.Content.GetAsync())
                    {
                        var fileName = $"{userId}_profile_pic.jpg";
                        using (var fileStream = File.Create(fileName))
                        {
                            await photoStream.CopyToAsync(fileStream);
                            Console.WriteLine($"Profile picture saved as: {fileName}");
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (ServiceException ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"Error downloading profile picture: {ex.Message}");
                }
            }
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            var handler = new GraphHandler();
            var userId = "UserID"; // Replace with the desired user's ID
            await handler.PrintProfilePicture(userId);
        }
    }
}



Reference:
Get a user - Microsoft Graph v1.0 | Microsoft

Sure, But I have some causing some issue when I was trying to get user photo: System.Net.Http.HttpConnection+ChunkedEncodingReadStream

What code are you using to get user photo?

using this Code: var user = await GraphClient.Users[userId].Photo.Content.GetAsync(); return user;  this is returning me error like this : System.Net.Http.HttpConnection+ChunkedEncodingReadStream

@Rukmini this is done using http client, but I am not using that method. that you know

@AshishPrajapati Check my updated answer to get user photo

It's Works and it is give me output that you mentioned as updated image, but I am not getting download Image, where it is stored?

Go to your file manager and search in home with the name you will find the file

Thanks I found it, can just Update once small thing, how can I Update that profile Image

Please post it as a new question so that I can help you there
